# Modifying Minix 3 Scheduler

Tags: c, operating-system, minix

I recently purchased this book to get a better understanding of how operating systems work. I am on the second chapter and I'm stuck on this problem and my OS does not boot with code I have added. The code below was added to proc.c at the start of the pic_proc function to try and modify the scheduler.

Modification.

```
int realtime;
clock_t recent_time[NR_TASKS + NR_PROCS];
clock_t stopwatch;

realtime = getuptime();
recent_time[proc_ptr->p_nr + NR_TASKS] = realtime - stopwatch;
stopwatch = realtime;
```

Original Code:

```
    PRIVATE void pick_proc()
    {
    register struct proc *rp;                     /* process to run */
    int q;                                        /* iterate over queues */
    
    /* Modified Code here */

     for (q=0; q < NR_SCHED_QUEUES; q++) {
        if ( (rp = rdy_head[q]) != NIL_PROC) {
              next_ptr = rp;                      
              if (priv(rp)->s_flags & BILLABLE)
                  bill_ptr = rp; 
     return;
      }
}
}
```

Book Operating Systems Design and Implementation. 3rd, Edition The Minix Book, P219, #45.
Modify the Minix 3 scheduler to keep track of how much CPU time each user process has had recently. When no task or server wants to run, pick the user process that has had the smallest share of the CPU.

[image: Enqueue Code]

[image: Sched part 1]

[image: Sched part 2]

Comment: _How_ does it "not boot"? Segfault, protection exception, etc.? Is `proc_ptr` _valid_ when your code is called? It might be `NULL`. Is `proc_ptr->p_nr` in the range 0 to `NR_PROC - 1`? If not, you've got UB [undefined behavior] and you're corrupting the stack [I assume `recent_time` is on the stack] because you're indexing beyond the end of `recent_time`. You should add `if` statement checks for validity and add [minux equiv of] `printk` to show the values. Maybe `realtime` should be `unsigned` [and/or `clock_t` as your setting `stopwatch` to its value]. Can `recent_time` fit on the stack?

Comment: Ive added the pic_proc function that i modified if that helps. After doing the make fresh install It will compile the new image. When I try to boot from that image it deadlocks and I have to shut it down and return to the previous image file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your new code [and the `pick_proc` function body], the only possible failures are the ones I've described above in my top comments.

That is, `proc_ptr` *must* be valid (i.e. non-NULL) and `proc_ptr->p_nr` must be in range to prevent UB.

What are the `NR_TASKS` and `NR_PROCS` values? Can `recent_time` fit on the stack? Stack size in a kernel is usually very limited. For example, under linux, you can only have about 4KB of stack.

So, if `NR_PROCS` was (e.g.) 32767, then `recent_time` could *not* be placed on the stack.

And, I don't see a reason the have an independent array for this on the stack as it won't persist past the call.

So, to aid in debug, I'd add `static` to the `recent_time` definition

You'll need to add some debug code to see what the issue is.

Here's a sample. Adjust the `printf` et. al. to suit the `minux` kernel's print mechanism [assuming you *can* print at the state your code is called in]:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

PRIVATE void
pick_proc()
{
    register struct proc *rp;           /* process to run */
    int q;                              /* iterate over queues */

    /* Modified Code here */
    int realtime;
    static clock_t recent_time[NR_TASKS + NR_PROCS];
    clock_t stopwatch;
    do {
        // bad pointer
        dbgprt("pick_proc: proc_ptr=%p\n",proc_ptr);
        if (proc_ptr == NULL)
            break;

        // out of range process number
        dbgprt("pick_proc: p_nr=%u\n",proc_ptr->p_nr);
        if (proc_ptr->p_nr >= NR_PROCS)
            break;

        realtime = getuptime();
        dbgprt("pick_proc: realtime=%d\n",realtime);
        recent_time[proc_ptr->p_nr + NR_TASKS] = realtime - stopwatch;
        stopwatch = realtime;
    } while (0);

    for (q = 0; q < NR_SCHED_QUEUES; q++) {
        if ((rp = rdy_head[q]) != NIL_PROC) {
            next_ptr = rp;
            if (priv(rp)->s_flags & BILLABLE)
                bill_ptr = rp;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I can't emphasize enough the importance of `assert` and/or `if` statements to pre-validate anything you do to prevent UB. And, *debug* `printf`, such as:

```
TRACE(VF_PICKPROC,printf("hello world\n"););
```

BTW, I pulled the `minix` source code from github:

git clone https://github.com/Stichting-MINIX-Research-Foundation/minix.git

It appears that you may have *outdated* source because the `pick_proc` in that repo has more SMP related code.

> The NR_TASKS + NR_PROCS should be the time quanta taken from the process table. I orginally declared the Array and stopwatch in proc.h but the pic_proc function did not have access to them.

You really want to either use the existing fields in `struct proc` or add some of your own vs. creating a separate array [indexed by process number].

> I added some screen shots of code that calls pic_proc. I think i need to modify sched and leave pic_proc alone. The array in pic_proc should be getting the time quanta from each process from the process table

Yes, hopefully elapsed CPU time for each process is in `struct proc`. If not, you'll have to add a field. I suspect that `p_user_time` [and/or `p_sys_time`] may be what you want. And, maybe, `p_cpu_time_left`. Other possibilities: `p_accounting.time_in_queue`. Or, `p_cycles`

`pick_proc` just looks at the head of a given run queue. So, you may need to change the code that actually inserts a given process into that queue. That *might* be `enqueue` and/or `dequeue`. They appear to honor process priority [`p_priority`] and preemption.

I've skimmed the kernel code, and at a *guess*, `sched_proc` may be of interest.

But, I really think you'll need to examine the kernel code more closely to see what functions actually add a process to a given run queue. And, how they select a process and from which queue.

When adding a process, it may just append to the tail. That code would need to scan the queue and [assuming the priority is the *same*], insert based on lowest CPU usage.

Comment: NB: In 2021 most linux systems have 8kb of default stack. (Which can be raised)

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Yes. I was doing it from memory [when it was 4KB]. But, I wanted to emphasize the limited nature of the resource. And, the fact OP's kernel "won't boot" would seem to indicate the code is called early in the boot process.

Comment: The NR_TASKS + NR_PROCS should be the time quanta taken from the process table. I orginally declared the Array and stopwatch in proc.h but the pic_proc function did not have access to them.

Comment: I added some screen shots of code that calls pic_proc. I think i need to modify sched and leave pic_proc alone. The array in pic_proc should be getting the time quanta from each process from the process table.